# Uninstall an Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu out of a USB stick and created a dual boot in my windows 8 computer.  Now I was informed to use another computer for Ubuntu's purpose and I want to undo what I've done.  Is there a quick way to do it without hurting my windows 8 environment?

Comment: This should work: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/